# Extract all numbers from a single string in R

Tags: regex, r

Let's imagine you have a string:

```
strLine <- "The transactions (on your account) were as follows: 0 3,000 (500) 0 2.25 (1,200)"
```

Is there a function that strips out the numbers into an array/vector producing the following required solution:

```
result <- c(0, 3000, -500, 0, 2.25, -1200)?
```

i.e.

```
result[3] = -500
```

Notice, the numbers are presented in accounting form so negative numbers appear between (). Also, you can assume that only numbers appear to the right of the first occurance of a number. I am not that good with regexp so would appreciate it if you could help if this would be required. Also, I don't want to assume the string is always the same so I am looking to strip out all words (and any special characters) before the location of the first number.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
x <- str_extract_all(strLine,"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?")[[1]]
> x
[1] "0"       "3,000"   "(500)"   "0"       "2.25"    "(1,200)"
```

Change the parens to negatives:

```
x <- gsub("\\((.+)\\)","-\\1",x)
x
[1] "0"      "3,000"  "-500"   "0"      "2.25"   "-1,200"
```

And then `as.numeric()` or `taRifx::destring` to finish up (the [next version](https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx/blob/22dd0968dbb9e9225164de96f2bffc11d62eed5a/R/Rfunctions.R#L1122) of `destring` will support negatives by default so the `keep` option won't be necessary):

```
library(taRifx)
destring( x, keep="0-9.-")
[1]    0 3000  -500    0    2.25 -1200
```

OR:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",","",x))
[1]     0  3000  -500     0     2.25 -1200
```

Comment: Hey, you're missing a period in your first regex. The result should have 2.25, not 2 and 25.

Comment: This is scary. Your regular expression work like i wanted. I tried like, 5 regex and none bring the values independent of the decimal sign (., ,), your do. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Here's the base R way, for the sake of completeness...

```
x <- unlist(regmatches(strLine, gregexpr('\\(?[0-9,.]+', strLine)))
x <- as.numeric(gsub('\\(', '-', gsub(',', '', x)))
[1]     0.00  3000.00  -500.00     0.00     2.25 -1200.00
```

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are concise and what I was looking for.

Comment: Remove the dot and second comma from the first line if you know all numbers are > 0, for example, when column names are numbered as in: `col.1 col.2 col.3`.

Comment: what if I would like to have it the other way. I have a data frame with negative values i want to replace them with () . please help

Comment: @ArunRaja your question warrants submitting a new question to the [r] tag.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde do you know the answer of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340345/make-first-and-last-row-of-a-dataframe-bold-using-tablegrob

Answer (score 1):

What for me worked perfectly when working on single strings in a `data frame` (One string per row in same column) was the following:

```
library(taRifx)
DataFrame$Numbers<-as.character(destring(DataFrame$Strings, keep="0-9.-"))
```

The results are in a new column from the same `data frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this came up in another question, this is an uncrutched `stringi` solution (vs the `stringr` crutch):

```
as.numeric(
  stringi::stri_replace_first_fixed(
    stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
      unlist(stringi::stri_match_all_regex(
        "The transactions (on your account) were as follows: 0 3,000 (500) 0 2.25 (1,200)", 
        "\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?"
      )), "\\)$|,", ""
    ),
    "(", "-"
  )
)
```