# Batch convert columns to numeric type

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns that I need to convert to the numeric type. I have written the following code to try to do this, however it is saying the replacement has 0 rows.

```
instanceconvert <- colnames(regmodel[7:262])

for (i in instanceconvert)
{
  regmodel$i <- as.numeric(regmodel$i)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The reason this is not working is that you are telling R to look for an object named `i` inside of `regmodel`. Inside your loop, `i` is the column itself, not the name of the column anyway.

Comment: And don't forget 8.2.1 in the R Inferno: www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12727871/636656

Answer (score 62):

You can use sapply for this:

```
dat <- sapply( dat, as.numeric )
```

If not every column needs converting:

```
library( taRifx )
dat <- japply( dat, which(sapply(dat, class)=="character"), as.numeric )
```

Comment: It may be useful to note that the class of `dat` is now `matrix`. 
`dat <- as.data.frame(sapply(dat, as.numeric)` allows for easier replacement.

Answer (score 12):

Combining the answer by @Andrii with the comment by @RobertYi, my short suggestion is

```
df[] <- sapply(df, as.numeric)
```

This ensures that the result stays a data frame and preserves column names (thanks, @krassowski).

Comment: It also preserves row names (while the most upvoted answer does not).

Answer (score 9):

Here is quick solution from other question:

`df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Reference: [Change all columns from factor to numeric in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915131/change-all-columns-from-factor-to-numeric-in-r)

Comment: What is the advantage of casting to character first and only then casting to numeric?

Comment: @bers: Factors are sometimes converted to weird numbers otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

As SenorO pointed out, the reason your original code does not work is that `$i` will not evaluate `i` to find out it's current value. You should instead access and assign to the column using double brackets, which work when `i` is a name or index number:

```
for (i in instanceconvert)
{
  regmodel[[i]] <- as.numeric(regmodel[[i]])
}
```

Following Ari's approach, you can get rid of the loop:

```
regmodel[,instanceconvert] <- 
    lapply(regmodel[,instanceconvert,drop=FALSE],as.numeric)
```

You could also do this with your range, 7:262, in place of "instanceconvert", since you can access/assign by name or column number.

Answer (score 3):

A fast a dirty way to do it, especially if you have variables all over that need converting, which would mean a lot of conversion code is to write the file out and read it back in again using something like write.csv/read.csv

```
write.csv(regmodel, file="regmodel.csv")
read.csv(file="regmodel.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the columns you want as a data frame `d` into the following:

```
data.frame(apply(d, 2, as.numeric))
```

This goes column by column and converts each into a numeric. Then just change your row-names and column-names accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Along with all of these approaches, if you have character/numeric/date type columns and want to convert (type of) them according to their value, the following may be useful:

```
type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```