# Identify if character string contains any numbers?

Tags: r

I've been trying to word this title for 5 minutes to avoid it being a similarly phrased question. No luck, so apologies if this has already been discussed. I couldn't find any other threads on this particular subject.

Simply put, I want to identify if numbers exist in a class character string. If true apply further functions.

Here's a dodgy attempt.

```
x <- "900 years old"

if(str_detect(x, ">=0")) {

print("contains numbers")
}
```

So obviously the problem is that I'm trying to use relational operators within a character string. Considering it's of this class, how can i identify numeric characters?

Comment: Here is another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727664/extract-all-numbers-from-a-single-string-in-r

Comment: Okay. I don't intend to extract the numbers, just boolean the string

Comment: Probably could be as simple `str_detect(x, "[0-9]")`, if you just want to test for one or more digits.

Comment: Yep nice, that worked. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[0-9]` is a regex pattern for numbers 0 to 9. You could also use special patterns `\d` or `[:digit:]` (for digits). In R, you have to add extra escapes to the special patterns. All of these should work:

```
str_detect(x, "[0-9]")
str_detect(x, "\\d")
str_detect(x, "[[:digit:]]")
```

Answer (score 3):

With `base R`, we can use `grepl`

```
grepl('[0-9]', x)
```